# parsley().validate() always returns true for remote validation fields

Tags: parsley.js

I have a form with remote field validation using [parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/):

```
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' required="true" data-parsley-trigger="focusout" data-parsley-remote="/ajax.php?UsernameExists" data-parsley-debounce="250"/>
```

Which works great, the field turns red when the username already exists, and green when the username is available.

Unfortunately upon clicking submit, I execute the following which always returns true, regardless of the username already exists or not:

```
form.parsley().isValid()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of isValid I did use whenValidate() which returns a jQuery promise.

```
form.parsley().whenValidate().done(function(){
   console.log('successfully validated');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`required` is treated differently than all other requirements. Check the doc for the `{force: true}` option.